# GET URL parameter in PHP

Tags: php, url, redirect

I'm trying to pass a URL as a url parameter in php but when I try to get this parameter I get nothing

I'm using the following url form:

```
http://localhost/dispatch.php?link=www.google.com
```

I'm trying to get it through:

```
$_GET['link'];
```

But nothing returned. What is the problem?

Comment: Show your full code

Comment: do `var_dump` of the `$_GET` param, it should be there

Comment: does `$_REQUEST['link']` work? Also keep in mind the index key `link` is case-sensitive to what's in the url.

Comment: You're not actually trying a `$_GET` but happening to be posting are you?

Comment: And what was the solution of this? Having the same problem

Comment: This normally works just fine in the situation you describe. We can't solve your problem without more information.

Comment: what happens if you call PUT with 'url/?id=5' and want to get that id out? How can you, probably not with $_GET since you called PUT (i send some data also)

Answer (score 354, accepted):

`$_GET` is not a function or language construct—it's just a variable (an array). Try:

```
<?php
echo $_GET['link'];
```

In particular, it's a [superglobal](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php): a built-in variable that's populated by PHP and is available in all scopes (you can use it from inside a function without the [global](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) keyword).

Since the variable might not exist, you could (and should) ensure your code does not trigger notices with:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['link'])) {
    echo $_GET['link'];
} else {
    // Fallback behaviour goes here
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to skip manual index checks and maybe add further validations you can use the [filter](http://php.net/filter) extension:

```
<?php
echo filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'link', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
```

Last but not least, you can use the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) (available since [PHP/7.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php)) to handle missing parameters:

```
echo $_GET['link'] ?? 'Fallback value';
```

Comment: If you got nothing with this, like me, than you should know, that 'link' is a name of variable in URL address! So with $_GET['link']; you need to enter URL like this: http://localhost/?link=test

Comment: I'm using WAMP on `localhost` and this solution it's not working. `http://localhost/station?type=2` `echo $_GET['type'];` is `null`

Comment: Finally I used `parse_str(parse_url($actual_link)['query'], $params);`. More info https://stackoverflow.com/a/11480852/4458531

Comment: You say "$_GET is not a function or language construct—it's just a variable (an array)" but we do not access values via index, instead you are accessing values via string.  Is this more of a dictionary than an array?

Comment: @ScottyBlades I'm speaking in the context of PHP data structures. In PHP, an [array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) is an ordered list of key/value combinations. That differs from what other languages (e.g. C or JavaScript) call "array".

Answer (score 31):

Please post your code,

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['link'];
?>
```

or

```
<?php
    echo $_REQUEST['link'];
?>
```

**do** work...

Answer (score 24):

Use this:

```
$parameter = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
echo $parameter;
```

Or just use:

```
$parameter = $_GET['link'];
echo $parameter ;
```

Answer (score 21):

To make sure you're always on the safe side, without getting all kinds of unwanted code insertion use FILTERS:

```
echo filter_input(INPUT_GET,"link",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

More reading on [php.net function filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php), or check out [the description of the different filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php)

Comment: Please note that this filter does not protect against any kind of attacks. This filter will however irreparably damage your data. Do not use it unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer is good. But if you have a scenario like this:

```
http://www.mydomain.me/index.php?state=California.php#Berkeley
```

You can treat the named anchor as a query string like this:

```
http://www.mydomain.me/index.php?state=California.php&city=Berkeley
```

Then, access it like this:

```
$Url = $_GET['state']."#".$_GET['city'];
```

Answer (score 5):

I was getting nothing for any `$_GET["..."]` (e.g `print_r($_GET)` gave an empty array) yet `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` showed stuff should be there. In the end it turned out that I was only getting to the web page because my .htaccess was redirecting it there (my 404 handler was the same .php file, and I had made a typo in the browser when testing).

Simply changing the name meant the same php code worked once the 404 redirection wasn't kicking in!

So *there are ways* `$_GET` can return nothing even though the php code may be correct.

Answer (score 5):

```
$Query_String  = explode("&", explode("?", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[1] );
var_dump($Query_String)
```

> Array
> (
> [  0] => link=www.google.com
> )