# Get the value from a form in PHP

Tags: php, forms, variables, get, call

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GET URL parameter in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884807/get-url-parameter-in-php)

(Mind you I am fairly new to PHP and still learning)
I have form:

```
<form name="checkingEmail">
        E-Mail: <input type="text" name="email1" />
        <br />
        Retype E-Mail: <input type="text" name="email2" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="checkEmail()">
    </form>
```

and I want to take the values from the User Input and do a simple If...Else statement after they hit "Submit"

PHP:

```
<?php
$email1 = blah //Value from email1 input form here;
$email2 = blah //Value from email2 input form here;
function checkEmail()
{
global $email1, $email2;
if($email1==$email2)
{
//Some Code Here
}
else
{
echo "Make sure your E-Mail addresses match";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: I can't believe the PHP tutorial you're learning from doesn't explain this. It's PHP 101.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the GET or POST variable on your form .. so include the method attribute in your form element:

```
<form method="get">
```

And then use GET or POST for a more secure approach ... the form input isn't shown in the URL when using the POST method.

You can use either like:

```
$email1 = $_POST['email1'];
$email2 = $_POST['email2'];
```

Comment: I agree, I would use the `post` method whenever possible over the `get` method in the form. :)

Comment: POST is not inherently more secure. Just because you don't see it in the browser adress bar, does not make it intamperable.

Comment: I am using this method, I changed my form to method="post" and using the $_POST to describe the variable, but I am not sure if it's working or not. I think there may be a problem with my submit button?

Comment: Everything you see in my form is what I have. Please explain this in an answer(:

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately something is going wrong...

Answer (score 0):

```
$email1 = $_GET['email1'];
$email2 = $_GET['email2'];
```

Then make sure that you call the `checkEmail()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You should also specify the sending method: POST or GET inside the form html:

-->GET

HTML:

```
    <form name="checkingEmail" method="get">
```

PHP:

```
    $email1 = $_GET['email1'];
```

-->POST

HTML:

```
    <form name="checkingEmail" method="post">
```

PHP:

```
    $email1 = $_POST['email1'];
```

Or you can check which type has a field passed.

HTML:

```
    <input type='hidden' name='check' />
```

PHP:

```
    if(isset($_POST['check'])) {
        // Post method
      } elseif(isset($_GET['check'])) {
        // Get method
      } else {
        // failure
      }
```