# hyperlinks pass data to next page in PHP

Tags: php

I have a code here where the referral name of each person has a hyperlink and when i click it, it will go to pick.php. For example I click "TEST7 TEST7", how do I pass the Lead No. of "TEST7 TEST7" which is LEA3330 to pick.php?

[image: Picture]

part of code in index.php

```
//print data in the table
echo '
<tr>
<td>'.$row['lead_no'].'</td>
<td><a href="pick.php"> '.$row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname'].'</a></td>
</tr>
';
```

Comment: Put it in the href as a GET parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php):

```
//print data in the the table
echo
"<tr>
    <td>{$row['lead_no']}</td>
    <td>
        <a href='pick.php?lead_no={$row['lead_no']}'>
            {$row['firstname'].$row['lastname']}
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>";
```

Then, access it from `pick.php` like so:

```
$lead_no = $_GET['lead_no'];
```

For future reference: [GET URL parameter in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884807/get-url-parameter-in-php)

Comment: do i put the code i posted in the "//the rest of your code"?

Comment: @marse, yes. Since you seem so unsure I've taken the liberty of doing it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value as a get parameter:

```
<a href="pick.php?leadno=<?php echo $row['lead_no']; ?>">
```

and then just use `$_GET['leadno']`

Comment: hello, do i replace my <a href="pick.php"> with your code? because when i replace it, it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data in the URL as query parameters. For example, instead of `next.php`, go to `next.php?key=value&key2=value2`. So when you're generating the page with the hyperlink, create a link with that extra part (it'll need to be URL encoded, also).

Then, you can use the special $_GET array in the `next.php` page to access those variables. For example, `$_GET['key']`.

Note that you shouldn't send anything private in the query params, or anything that you wouldn't want someone to bookmark, share the link to, etc. So you mustn't use query params to submit forms, say. Read up on GET versus POST [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

Answer (score 0):

In pick.php just use the $_GET['leadno'];