# How to pass data from an email to a landing page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

So my question is that for example lets say a

customer receives an email 
and then they click on the link which is in the email that they receive
What I want to do is that when they click on the link 
this link will take them to a webpage where there will be a form
What the webpage should do is automatically fill in the customers details depending on who the customer was so for example their email address, firstname and lastname.

What is the best way to do this? I was thinking of using PHP but is it possible to do using Javascript or any other languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass user email or any other information in url using abc.com?data=email and then you retrieve details from your db and don't forget to escape the get parameter for security reasons

set url data like http://localhost/dispatch.php?link=www.google.com
so here link will be your get parameter check on the link given below
refer this link:[GET URL parameter in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884807/get-url-parameter-in-php)

Comment: Hey thanks for this but could you give me an example so that I can get my head around this properly?

Comment: So you see this URL data will that be generated when they click on the link that will be in the email that they receive?

Comment: you have all the data of users that u send emails then when user click on the link you can get the url parameter and filter it and pass to query and then fetch data this url is just example

Answer (score 1):

Only GET data can be sent from an email. 
So you can pass the email : mylandingpage.com?email@email.com

Then you could retrieve the user informations from your database (PHP/MySQL)

Comment: Hey thanks for this but could you give me an example so that I can get my head around this properly?