# Getting url parameters in php variables

Tags: php, url

I tried following code  [GET URL parameter in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884807/get-url-parameter-in-php) to fetch URL parameters into a string but none of the answer worked. I tried `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];`. This worked some how and gives a query string as `action=quantity_updated&id=1&name=Top&price=24&qty=4` from this URL: `http://localhost/Ecommerce/cart.php?action=quantity_updated&id=1&name=Top&price=24&qty=4`. Some suggesstions please. How can I fetch each parameter in a separate php variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$action = $_GET['action'];
$id = $_GEt['id'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
```

and so on