# How do I redirect with PHP and save the link in SQL?

Tags: php, sql, redirect, logging, save

I have XAMPP and I want to write a simple PHP page, that redirects me to the link that I specify, and also saves the link in an SQL database.

Let's say I want to visit www.google.com:

I'd visit something like:

```
localhost:80/redirect.php?url=https://google.com
```

And PHP would redirect me there and also save the www.google.com link in an SQL table.

Can you help me out?

Comment: what have you got so far? `$_GET['url']` <add to db use `header()` to redirect.

Comment: What did you try? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 4):

Considering how you formed your question, it looks as if you had an idea an just want someone to give you the solution without you even making an effort *(please correct me if I'm wrong but that's how it seams...)*

The task you are trying to achieve is a simple one, and it's only fair to point you in the right direction. your "task" can be broken into several smaller ones:

1. Create database / table for storing data | [PHP Create MySQL Tables](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create_table.asp)
2. [Get URL parameter in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884807/get-url-parameter-in-php)
3. [PHP Insert Data Into MySQL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)
4. [How to make a redirect in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Sorry if this is not the kind-a answer you are looking for, but I figure the point of this website is for people to learn something and not just copy+paste. The provided links can be used to solve your task problem.

Comment: I'm stuck here: $sql = "INSERT INTO log (link, last_visit_date, visit_count)
VALUES ($link , $datetime , 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
last_visit_date = $datetime, visit_count = visit_count + 1 ";
but <link> is of TEXT/VARCHAR(256) and can't be PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: I'm also stuck here: $sql = "REPLACE INTO log (link, last_visit_date, visit_count)
SELECT ($link , $datetime , 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
last_visit_date = $datetime, visit_count = visit_count + 1 "; because <link> is of TEXT/VARCHAR(256) and can't be PRIMARY KEY

Comment: and finally, I'm stuck here: $sql = "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM logging WHERE link=$link) THEN
    UPDATE log SET last_visit_date = $datetime, visit_count = visit_count + 1 WHERE link=$link
ELSE
    INSERT INTO log (link, last_visit_date, visit_count) VALUES ($link , $datetime , 1)
END IF";

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, after MySQLi Object-oriented did not validate this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM logging WHERE link=$link";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {}
```

It still increments the number of visits sometimes by +2. I don't know why.

```
  <?php
    $servername = " ";
    $username = " ";
    $password = " ";
    $dbname = " ";

    $datetime = date_create()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $datetime = "'".$datetime."'";

    $link_clean = $_GET['link'];    
    $link = "'".$link_clean."'";


    // Create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM logging WHERE link=$link";

    if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) 
    {

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
        {
            $sql="UPDATE logging SET last_visit_date = $datetime, visit_count = visit_count + 1 WHERE link=$link";
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql))  {
                $conn->close();
                header("Location: https://$link_clean");
                exit;
            } else {
                echo "1Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
                $conn->close();
                exit;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $sql="INSERT INTO logging (link, last_visit_date, visit_count) VALUES ($link , $datetime , 1)";
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                mysqli_close($conn);
                header("Location: https://$link_clean");
                exit;
            } else {
                echo "2Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
                mysqli_close($conn);
                exit;
            }
        }
    } 

    else 
    {
        echo "3Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```