# Store data/<select> on client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, session-cookies

I have a HTML page with couple of div and 2 drop down list . values in drop down list is loaded based on selection made in list 1 (both the list are getting values from DB), such that Every time user selects a value from drop down list 2 .. value is passed as as parameter and the page is reloaded to display the values in div present on the page.

Problem is with the refresh of page select list values are also refreshed and user is again asked to select the values from the list.

As per my knowledge we can store single values in cookies .. is it possible to store a list, also apart from cookies is there any other way to store entire drop down list on client side ?

**I am using php for server side scripting and java script on client side**

Comment: Look into [LocalStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage).

Comment: Several things could be done.  You could use url query parameters, cookie, localstorage.  Any of those sound like they could be options for your case.

Comment: Use ajax to update the content ... in this day and age reloading page using select is a thing of the past and isn't very user friendly

Comment: @charlietfl yes initially i was using ajax to load the page .. but we need to make the link easy to share .. so i have to pass selected value as parameter in URL  and reload the page

Comment: then why aren't you setting the values server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you can store whatever you want in [**cookies**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie), not just a single value. You could store it as a JSON string: `{"dropdown1":"value","dropdown2:"value"}` and parse the value in the cookie on reload.

Or you could redirect to the same url but using a [**query parameter**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5884896/1495728): `www.example.com/form.php?dropdown1=value` and grab the value from there.

Or you could put it into [**local storage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage): `localStorage.setItem("dropdown1", "value");`