# Insert a value from the URL (PHP)

Tags: php

I'll try to explain myself good as i can,
I have this "value"

[image: Picture here]

And i want to do something that, when I enter to this link for example:
http://example.com/index.php?value=50
It will insert the number 50 into the value..

```html
<input type="number" name="amount" min="1" max="5000" value=""  />
```

Someone can help  me please?

Thanks everyone the problem solved

Comment: this is basic knowledge you can find every where with example on the internet,

Comment: This is not a jobs board. We are not here to "help" you. You show what you've attempted, explain what it SHOULD be doing, explain how it's NOT doing that, and we'll (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: Well, Beleive me that I already tried.  Can you help?

Comment: @Ben Show us your PHP first?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884807/get-url-parameter-in-php

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="number" name="amount" min="1" max="5000" value="<?php echo (isset($_GET['value']) ? $_GET['value'] : '') ?>"  />
```

isset() is in place just in case the 'value' parameter has not been passed via the url

Answer (score 0):

URLs usually come in this format (see [query strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) on Wikipedia):

```
protocol://baseurl/path?queryparam1=value1&queryparam2=value2&queryparam3=value3...
```

In your URL, `value` is a *GET query parameter* and `50` is its value.

Access the query parameters with the PHP [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) global array. Its keys are set to the values of the query parameters.

For example, the value "50" will be stored in `$_GET['value']`. You can store this in the `value` of your input element like so:

```
<input type="number" name="amount" min="1" max="5000" value="<?= $_GET['value'] ?>" />
```

(`<?= $value ?>` is the shortcut for `<?php echo $value ?>`, and can be used in PHP5.4+)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to retrieve the value from the URL (don't forget to sanitize the user input):
`<?php $value = htmlspecialchars($_GET['value']); ?>`

Then, when you want to insert the value in your html, you just use `<?php echo $value; ?>`

For instance `<input type="number" name="amount" min="1" max="5000" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />`

Comment: erh, say value contains a double quote and a `>`?