# Catch values of parameters in Php sent from angularJs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, parameters, parameter-passing

I am working first time on php. I want to pass my parameters from angularJs to a php file then those parameters are supposed to be used in INSERT query. I have used XmlHttpRequest to call php file (addsubscriber.php?par1=val1&par2=val2) through AngularJs Function (vm.addSub). Now I dont know how to catch those parameters in my php file.

AngularJs

```
vm.addSub = function(){

            var params = "name="+vm.selectedNameAdd+"&number="+vm.selectedPhoneAdd+"&status="+vm.selectedStatusAdd;
            var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            oReq.onload = function(){
                vm.msg = JSON.parse(this.responseText);   
            };
            oReq.open("get", "addSubscriber.php?"+params, true);
            console.log("addSubscriber.php?"+params);
            oReq.send();
        };
          });
```

addSubscriber.php (What have I tried so far is commented in my php file)

```
    <?php

 include('connectionString.php');
 $dbObj = new connectionString();
 $conn = $dbObj->getdbconnect();


// $request = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input')   );
//           $name -> name;
//           $number -> number;
//           $status -> status;

   // $name = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL ); // $_GET['name'];
   // $number = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'number', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL ); // $_GET['number'];
  // $status = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'status', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL ); // $_GET['status'];
//  parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $query = "INSERT INTO SUBSCRIBERS(subscriber_name,subscriber_number,created_on,is_active) VALUES($name,$number,$date,$status)";
    if(mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conn'], $query)){
      $msg = "Inserted Successfully";
    }
     else{
         $msg = "Insertion Failed";
     }
     print json_encode($msg);
```

Comment: check this [GET URL parameter in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884807/get-url-parameter-in-php)

Comment: I have already tried things from the referred question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was with Query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO SUBSCRIBERS(subscriber_name,subscriber_number,created_on,is_active) VALUES('$name','$number','$date','$status')";
```

Note the single quotes in VALUES part. 
After adding single quotes it worked as desired.