# How to link to pages within a php file with page.php?secondpage

Tags: php

I'm looking to divide up my page into smaller sections for ease of organising my content. Other websites I've seen have used the system of having the main page url then a question mark and the next page name after it (eg. www.website.com/page.php?secondpage)

For what I want to achieve, see an example [here](http://www.cassidy.milkbaeri.net/tcgs/sakura.php) (under collecting, current, etc). For my current page, see [here](http://all-alight.net/tcg/sakura.php).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you have to improve your knowledge of PHP, then show us what you have tried so we can help you.

Comment: Read the manual about [$_POST and $_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) and then about `include()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GET URL parameter in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884807/get-url-parameter-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this in your html 
    a href="page.php?collections">collections

in your php code, you can write

```
<?php if($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] == 'collections'){ ?>

//second page code goes here

<?php } ?>
```