# load a file using variable from client side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to load a file inside a container, but using an argument - to get some data from database firstly:

```
$('#story').load('test.php');
```

**test.php**

```
$st = $db->query("select * from users where id = " . $id);  

... processing variables... load the finished content
```

Here I need `$id` from client side. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GET URL parameter in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884807/get-url-parameter-in-php)

Comment: note that you should be very cautious not injecting directly the variable in your SQL string. [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) -> you should use prepared statements, and maybe do some checks first

Comment: @Kaddath sql injection on `select` statement?

Comment: yes, that can be used to get informations about other tables of your DB, using join and such, good habit to take anyway

Comment: @Kaddath, thanks, I believed select statement is safe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes ..you could pass with `url query`

```
$('#story').load('test.php?id=1');
```

**test.php**

```
$id = isset($_REQUEST['id'])?$_REQUEST['id']):'';
$st = $db->query("select * from users where id = " . $id);
```

Comment: You can use null coalesce operator instead ternery operator as $id = $_REQUEST['id] ?? '';

Comment: @RohitGhotkar you are right.But its only supported on php 7 and above.Not with lower version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571330/php-ternary-operator-vs-null-coalescing-operator

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax request and on success you load your file something like:

```
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: "test.php", //make sure you put the right path there
                        data: {id: id},
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (resultData) {
                            $('#story').load('test.php');
                        }
                    })
```

Just make sure that your php function returns/echos the id you want.

That way you make a call to your php file and when it's successful you will load your file and you can put extra logic there if you want to return more data to use it of course.

`resultData` holds the output of your php function so it's up to you what info you want to be there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Ajax** to post the `ID` to your php code.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "test.php",
data: { 'id': foo },
cache: false,
success: function(){
   alert("Order Submitted");
  }
});
```

php:

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
```