# PHP file not updating after selecting from drop down

Tags: php, html, ajax, dropdown

I have two separate files, `bargraph.html` and `data.php`.

Part of bargraph:

```
<form method="POST" name="dataform" action="" id='dataForm'>
  <select id="data1" name="data1">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="DateRecorded">DateRecorded</option>
    <option value="InletVoltage">InletVoltage</option>
    <option value="InletCurrent">InletCurrent</option>
    <option value="ActivePower">ActivePower</option>
    <option value="ApparentPower">ApparentPower</option>
    <option value="PowerFactor">PowerFactor</option>
    <option value="SystemID">SystemID</option>
    </select>
    <select id ="data2" name="data2">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="DateRecorded">DateRecorded</option>
    <option value="InletVoltage">InletVoltage</option>
    <option value="InletCurrent">InletCurrent</option>
    <option value="ActivePower">ActivePower</option>
    <option value="ApparentPower">ApparentPower</option>
    <option value="PowerFactor">PowerFactor</option>
    <option value="SystemID">SystemID</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" id="submitButton" name="submitButton">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#submitButton').click(function(e) {
      var data1 = $("#data1").val();
      var data2 = $("#data2").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'data.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {data1:data1,data2:data2},
            success: function(data){ 
                console.log(data);
                console.log('#dataForm');
            }, 
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                console.log(thrownError);
            }, 
            complete: function(){
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

</script>
```

Part of data.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['data1'])) { 
    $opp1 = $_POST['data1']; 
} else { 
    $opp1 = 'SystemID'; 
}
if (isset($_POST['data2'])) { 
    $opp2 = $_POST['data2']; 
} else { 
    $opp2 = 'ApparentPower'; 
}

$sql = "SELECT $opp1, $opp2 FROM RaritanMachineDataa"; 
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql); 
$data = array(); 
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $row = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $row);
    $data[] = $row; 
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($result); 
sqlsrv_close($conn); 
echo json_encode($data); 
?>
```

When I select from the two drop down menus, in my `browser console`, it prints that chosen data in JSON format and the values from my database, however when I load the `data.php` file via `browser URL`, it is printing `SystemID` and `ApparentPower` and not the chosen data. Why is this? Can someone help me please?

See below screenshot of browser console printing the chosen data from drop downs.
https://imgur.com/rdxgWaB

and screenshot of data.php loaded via browser after choosing from drop down `InletCurrent` and `ActivePower`.
https://imgur.com/a/eiDeTLs

Comment: That's exactly the behaviour you've programmed. If POST `data1` is not set use `SystemID` if POST `data2` is not set use `ApparentPower`. Browsing `data.php` is a GET request thus no POST arguments are set.

Comment: @Sebastian How do I go about fixing this so it loads the POST data in my data.php via browser URL?

Comment: You could use query parameters [See php GET variables](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).  But in this case you have to update your ajax-call to also use query params.

Comment: @Sebastian Okay I have tried replacing POST in my data.php file with GET instead.. Am I doing it correctly? I cannot find an example online close to my program. Could you provide an example for my code on how to use GET please?

Comment: Just use $_GET instead of $_POST. And in the url you use something like `data.php?data1=SystemID&data2=ApparentPower`. [See this post for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884807/get-url-parameter-in-php)

Comment: @Sebastian I don't want the page to change when user clicks on "submit". I want the data to be inserted into the select query in data.php and then outputted to data.php when loading via URL. Is that possible to do? Because I have another JS file which read from the data.php file and updates a chart based on the data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `dataType: 'html'`
You post the `json` data but define the `html`
Try to change to json :

```
         $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'data.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {data1:data1,data2:data2},
            success: function(data){ 
                console.log(data);
                console.log('#dataForm');
            }, 
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                console.log(thrownError);
            }, 
            complete: function(){
            }
        });
```

Comment: I just tried this earlier, it just prints `SystemID` and `ApparentPower` in my browser console and data.php file via URL. Do I need to change something in `bargraph.html`?

Comment: Try `youhost/data.php?data1=DateRecorded&data2=InletVoltage`

Comment: Yes the form action and form method changed in `bargraph.html`, do you try my code?

Comment: Do I need to take out my ajax call or change the ajax call to GET?

Comment: Can we talk in chat?

Comment: remove your ajax call, change `bargraph.html` and `data.php` like me

Comment: what about the submit button function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189061/discussion-between-ryuk-lee-and-danny).