# Move Product Details Over To Form

Tags: php

When I press the "Buy Now" button, I would like it to copy over my product details (Name, Price & Image) and take me over to a checkout form; where I can 'purchase' the product.

Right now when I click the "Buy Now" button it will take me to an HTML page with a checkout form (without the product details).

```
    {

    $link = "checkout.html";
    $button = "button";        
    $style = "style=";
    print "<div class='product-card'<h4 style='padding:1em;'><b>" . $info['Name']."</h4></b><h4><b>Price: $". $info['Price']."</b></h4><img src=../images/".$info['ProductID'].".png ".$style."width:180px;height:120px;><br><br><a href=".$link."><button class=".$button.">Buy Now</button></a></div>";

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP and `$_GET` variables will be the easiest way.
Your link will look something like this:
`checkout.php?name=productName&price=1234&image=productImage`

Then on the purchase page you can get those variables with:

```php
$price = $_GET['price'];
etc...
```

However please be aware that **this is not safe**. Users could easily manipulate those variables by changing the URL.

Instead you **should** only place the `productId` in the URL like so:
`checkout.php?productId=1234`

Then on the purchase page you can access the database for the product details like the name, image, price etc. using the `productId` from the URL with `$_GET['productId']`.

More information about using `$_GET` variables: [GET URL parameter in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884807/get-url-parameter-in-php)
and [from the PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: So I would change the link code to the one you made for me. But what actually would the code be for displaying the product, or displaying the product information in a form to checkout?

Comment: @RonaldAdams You could use the productId from the URL to make a Database call and retrieve the specific product information. Then you could do the same as you are doing now with `$info['Name']` for example to display the product details on the purchase page.