# Detect javascript window.location.href with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I want php to work if a special header is sent with javascript. The javascript code looks like

```
indow.location.href="index.php?function=ladegueter";
```

How detect with php if this url is called?

Comment: Have you heard of [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)?

Comment: in `index.php` write this `<?php print_r($_GET); ?>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GET URL parameter in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884807/get-url-parameter-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, use `$_GET`:

```php
<?php

$function = $_GET['function'];

echo $function;

?>
```