# How can i get a Parameter From URL?

Tags: php, url, get

I want to get the TOKEN from the URL bar and name it in an echo. How can i do this?

I have tried:

```
$GET['Token']
```

```
http://forexample.de/getsharelink.php/TOKEN=d5bETQi8Iwe6G8tcIlWp
```

Comment: are you trying to get it in php or javascript? is that url the url that is calling the script or is it a string from a variable.

Comment: And for PHP:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884807/get-url-parameter-in-php/5884896

Comment: Case and there's a `_` in there.  Check the manual.

Comment: @devlincarnate Likely not

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to get it in PHP, the URL parameters are case sensitive, so it would be: `$_GET['TOKEN']`

Answer (score 0):

For the parameters, your URL needs to separate them from the main URL with `?` if you are wishing to use $_GET. For example, `http://forexample.de/getsharelink.php?TOKEN=d5bETQi8Iwe6G8tcIlWp`.

Other than that, you have simply missed out a _ before GET, also make sure your cases are correct.

Try this `$_GET['TOKEN']`