# How i can foreach php with google sheet api

Tags: php

[image]

I use googlesheet api and php for this project but output to show all record. I want to show ID that I want . How i do this

```
<?php }
          else{
            echo $message;
            foreach ($values as  $value) {
               $countRow++; ?>
                    <tr> <form method='post' action='' id="form<?=$countRow?>">
                             <td><input class='inputRow' id="number<?=$countRow?>" readonly='' type='text' name='number' value="<?=$value[0]?>"></td>
                             <td><input class='inputRow' id="docdate<?=$countRow?>" readonly='' type='text' name='docdate' value="<?=$value[1]?>">
                             
                             <input type='hidden' name='row' value="<?=$countRow?>"></td>
                             <td><input class='inputButton' id="btn<?=$countRow?>" type='submit' name='update' value='update'>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="deleteClass" onclick="btnData(this.id)" id="bt-<?=$countRow?>">Edit</a>
                                <input class='deleteClass' id="btnDelete<?=$countRow?>"  type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete'>
                             </td>
                          </form>
                      </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            
        }
   
             ?>
```

Comment: `echo $_GET["number"]` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GET URL parameter in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884807/get-url-parameter-in-php)

Comment: echo $_GET["number"]  where i write to code please tell me ,sir

Comment: stackoverflow is not a website which provides free courses in PHP (or English) so please look at the link in my previous comment, or look at the docs for [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)